# activityindicator animating in navigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app am downloading images and songs by using the following methods

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
-(void) handleResponse :(NSDictionary *) responsedata
```

and i wrote  the following in viewDidLoad.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 44);
UIBarButtonItem *actItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.navView] ;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actItem;
self.activityIndicator.hidden  = YES;
```

And in my class one button is there when i press the button(means downloading images and songs from url) activityindicator should animate.

in button action i wrote like

```
 self.activityIndicator.hidden  = NO;
 [self.activityIndicator staryAnimating];
```

But when i click on button Activityindicator is not diplaying.

Comment: r u adding activity indicator as IBOutlet or by code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
UIBarButtonItem *indicatorBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.activityIndicator];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:indicatorBtn animated:YES];
```

and then call this

```
self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/add-uiactivityindicatorview-to-uinavigationbar.php

Answer (score 1):

- replace following line I think its spell mistake --

  [self.activityIndicator staryAnimating];

  to

  [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];